# Don't understand why I get an "Expected an indented block" error with Pyomo

Tags: python, pyomo

I would like to use the following code from Pyomo [Accessing solver status and termination conditions](http://www.pyomo.org/blog/2015/1/8/accessing-solver)

```
results = opt.solve(instance) # Solving a model instance  
instance.load(results) # Loading solution into results object

if (results.solver.status == SolverStatus.ok) and (results.solver.termination_condition == TerminationCondition.optimal):
    # Do something when the solution in optimal and feasible
elif (results.solver.termination_condition == TerminationCondition.infeasible):
    # Do something when model in infeasible
else:
    # Something else is wrong
    print “Solver Status: ”,  result.solver.status
```

Hoever, I get an error saying `Expected an indented block` at the `elif`. When inserting an indented block, I get the error `Invalid syntax`. I posted a screenshot of both cases. I do not understand why I get this error? I just copied and pasted the code from the official pyomo website. Do you have any idea why I am getting this error and how I can get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: The comments don't count as statements. You need to put something in each block. `pass` will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need to have at least 1 line of executable code within each `if` or `elif` block.  Right now, you just have a comment line.

While you are "shelling out" the program, just put the command `pass` in each block and see if that helps.  So:

```
if (something >= something_else):
    # do something
    pass
else:
    # do the other thing
    pass
....
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer AirSquid. I upvoted and accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

When code is laid out using whitespace like python, you need something actually in the block to show that it's there. A comment isn't enough as these are ignored.

Your code currently looks like:

```
if ... :
    # comment where block should be
elif ... :
    print "something"
```

The comment doesn't count as an indented block.

If you really have no code to put in there yet, you can use the no-op statement `pass`:

```
if ... :
    # todo
    pass
elif ... :
    print "something"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer SpoonMeiser. I upvoted it.